# Web app to analyze domain name quality?

Tags: web-apps, analytics, url

A couple years ago I found a website that would calculate a given domain's quality based off a couple of factors like:

Domain length

Use of common words in the dictionary

TLDs

This website would then give a letter grade as a score for the domain name you type in. I used it a couple of times but I didn't bookmark it and I forgot what the name of the website was. I've had this in the back of my mind for years and I have tried to find it many many times on google but I haven't been able to.

Has anyone used this website before or know of one similar?

Comment: Sorry, Spencer: This site is about *software* recommendations, not *website* recommendations.

Comment: @Izzy:  Would this be on-topic for another Stack Exchange?  Perhaps webapps.SE or webmasters.SE?  If so, could we flag it for migration?

Comment: Dear Spencer:  Why do you want to find such a website?

Comment: @unforgettableid nope. There is [Website Recommendations](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80273/website-recommendations) at Area51, but it doesn't seem to be very active (so I doubt it goes public that soon).

Comment: @Izzy:  The webmasters.SE help pages say that [domain-related questions are on-topic](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @tealhill have you read the off-topic part of that page as well? Quote: "Recommendations for sites and resources". So: No.

Comment: @Izzy:  I didn't read the off-topic part of the page.  I now stand corrected; thank you.

Comment: Dear Spencer:  I see that you've found an acceptable answer (holroy's answer below), but for the future, please don't ask for website recommendations here.  Reddit is a broader venue, and accepts a wider variety of questions.  For example, this question could have gone to https://www.reddit.com/r/SEO/ instead.  cc:  @Izzy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are looking for a specific site, and there are quite a few to choose from I did a search on your bullet points, and found an umbrella site,  [DomainGroovy](//domaingroovy.com/), which has this to say about them self:

> Finding a good domain name is hard. DomainGroovy is here to help. Below are websites to help you in your quest for the perfect domain. Dozens of websites organized and rated for your convenience.

I suspect this site might list the one you are looking for. Maybe it is [NameStation](//namestation.com/) which according to DomainGroovy can *Generate random names with and without a root keyword. Control language, length, extension and more.*